# What happens after the parent of zombie process terminates?

Tags: c, linux, zombie-process

I'm just curious, what happens to zombie process, if it's parent doesn't care to wait for it.

Suppose, we've a parent and a child. Child terminates before parent does.

From APUE:

> The kernel keeps a small amount of information for every terminating process...Minimally
>   this information consists of the process ID, the termination status of the process....

Parent is required to fetch this information using `waitpid()`.
But if, parent exits without waiting for child, what happens:

Does the kernel delete this information (certainly it's of no use)?
Or, it keeps collecting this junk?
Is this implementation specific?
Or, is there a standard way to deal with this situation?

Comment: [`init process`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) become parent of child process., init flush entry from process table

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Orphan processes are automatically adopted by `init` which has a standard `SIGCHLD` handler that just discards any exit status of a dead process.

In your case if the parent of a zombie process dies the zombie orphan will be adopted by init and cleaned up.

The following code tests this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main() {
    pid_t child_pid;
    if (child_pid = fork()) { // fork a child, child will exit straight away
        char name[128];
        sprintf(name, "/proc/%d/stat", child_pid);
        char line[2048];

        // read childs /proc/pid/stat, field 3 will give its status
        FILE * fp = fopen(name, "r");

        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
            puts(line);

        fclose(fp);

        usleep(5000000);

        // by now the child will have exited for sure, repeat
        fp = fopen(name, "r");

        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
            puts(line);

        fclose(fp);

        // make another child to repeat the process and exit the parent
        if (!fork()) {
            usleep(5000000);
            // both parent and child will have exited by now

            fp = fopen(name, "r");

            // this should fail because init has already cleaned up the child
            if (!fp) {
                perror("fopen");
                return -1;
            }

            while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
                puts(line);

            fclose(fp);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since child has already terminated, will the `SIGCHLD` signal still be generated? I thought that it is generated, when the child terminates (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @mohit Good question, probably not. Can't say because I know of no way to adopt a process in a user process. Either way `init` cleans up the child discarding it's exit status. The whole adoption by init was introduced to make sure orphan zombies don't stay in the system.

Comment: +1, for the program. It really explains, what happens. However, I'm interested in how this is implemented. And if this is implementation specific, or is there a standard way.

Comment: @mohit It's Unix and Unix-like standard. And about `SIGCHLD` - `init` periodically waits for all it's children to clean them up if necessary. From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process